# Setting up route for method to find using token and not ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Issue: For when a user isn't signed in, they have no access to their Order Show page.  So I have created an order confirmations method in my OrdersController like so:

```
def order_confirmation
    @order = Order.find_by(order_token: params[:order_token])
  end
```

Now, as you see I am currently using a `order_token` `find_by` which uses a `to_param` override.

I want to avoid using the override since it applies controller wide and I haven't figured out a way to not have it used only on the one method only. This messes up my associated models as you can see here: [Why is my :order_token being passed as my :order_id when submitting a form file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101136/why-is-my-order-token-being-passed-as-my-order-id-when-submitting-a-form-file)

How can I make it so my route:

```
resources :orders do
      get 'order_confirmation', :on => :member
  end
```

without the use of the `to_param` override uses a URL such as :

```
example.com/orders/:order_token/order_confirmation
```

?

**Update and possible answer:**

I will make this the answer rafter some further testing.

**When using:**

```
  resources :orders, param: :order_token do
      get 'order_confirmation', :on => :member
  end
```

In my routes, I am able to go to the URL i want.  Although, after an order is created, it still directs me to a route using the :id.

**I then change my redirect to:**

```
redirect_to order_confirmation_order_path(@order.order_token)
```

And it works.

I also removed my `to_param` override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When using:**

```
  resources :orders, param: :order_token do
      get 'order_confirmation', :on => :member
  end
```

In my routes, I am able to go to the URL i want. Although, after an order is created, it still directs me to a route using the :id.

**I then change my redirect to:**

```
redirect_to order_confirmation_order_path(@order.order_token)
```

**And it works.**

I also removed my `to_param` override.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you'll want to `resources :orders, param: :order_token`

and then in your Order model

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  def to_param
    order_token
  end
end
```

this will have side effects throughout your app.

Rails guides has more info on [Overriding Named Route Parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters)

Comment: As i mentioned, I already have the override in place.  I want to avoid this because it becomes controller wide and I haven't figured out a way to limit it to only the orders_confirmation method

Comment: @uno Sorry, looked over that (on mobile); If you really needed to do this, I would recommend not using route helpers (order_order_confirmation_path) and just hardcoding it.

Comment: Haha no problem.  I actually might have found a way and im just testing it out.  It was much simpler than i previously thought.